# How to allow access to the same controller by both admin and user in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i have two guards `admin` and `users` and here `users` are of different type

`-users 
     -BD
     -SPOC
     -RECRUITOR
     -LEADERSHIP`

now I have some controllers which i want both admin and user to access.if anyone of them is logged in.but i dont want to allow anybody else to access it without login.

This is my controller

class AdminController extends Controller
{

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/admin/login';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
}
```

}

in the above controller if i use middleware -auth:admin then only admin will be able to access it and if i use middleware-auth only then i will take the user to user login screen.i want if anybody between admin or user of type leadership is logged in then they are able to access this controller.

**i want or condition in middleware to check either this or that ie middleware between auth or auth:admin not both**
how do i do this?
i m using `laravel`.i m new to this please help

Comment: Laravel uses middlewares to handle requests. You can specify middleware in routes. You can also use __construct() function to specify permissions to access controller methods.
Read the doc [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)

Answer (score 0):

### Your can use multiple `middlewares` in your `controllers`

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:web,admin');
    }
```

> *`Admin`* and *`user`* both have **access to page**

### Same you can do in your routes

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth:web,admin']], function() {
Route::get('url','somecontroller@method');
});
```

> You need one of above

#### `Web` is the default `guard` defined in your `config/auth.php`

When you are using this somewhere

```
public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
```

Will work same as below, because `web guard` is placed by default

```
public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth:web');
        }
```

Comment: i want if users is logged in then also he will be able to access it and if admin is logged then also able to access it .i want to middleware that will check either of the two not both

Comment: middleware to check between auth and auth:admin

Comment: `web` is the default guard, you can use `web` as user `guard`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the  [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware) concept.Middleware is checking in route file.Below way to check user auth.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin.user'], function () {
// Your routes which you want to allow after login
}
```